# Inserting landsat image WMS to MapServer map file?

Tags: wms, mapserver, landsat

I am trying to insert this landsat image to my Mapserver map file. However, I can not manage it. Does someone have an idea?

**Landsat image WMS information:**
[image]

```
Landsat from onearth.jpl.nasa.gov
Bounding box: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0) (show on OSM)
Projection: NASA:4326
WMS half-link: http://irs.gis-lab.info/?layers=landsat&
Tiles URL: http://irs.gis-lab.info/?layers=landsat&request=GetTile&z=!&x=!&y=!
```

**my mapfile layer:**

```
LAYER
    NAME global_landsat
    TYPE RASTER
    STATUS DEFAULT
    CONNECTIONTYPE WMS
    CONNECTION "http://irs.gis-lab.info/?layers=landsat&"
    MINSCALE 20000
        METADATA
            "wms_server_vesion" "1.1.1"
            "wms_srs"  "EPSG:4326"
            "wms_format" "image/png"
            "wms_name" "modis,global_mosaic"
        END
    END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you said, I corrected vesion as version and I can see the WMS layer now.

Comment: You should mark the answer (tick underneath the number / arrows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tiny literal error in your metadata:

use `wms_server_ve`**r**`sion` instead of `wms_server_vesion`.

Everything should work fine.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts because every post you make here is already signed by your [user card](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/39809/tee).  This is documented in the help which leads on from the 2-minute [Tour] which you appear to have not yet taken.